# If $a^2 +1/a^2=38$, find $a-1/a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a^2 +\dfrac{1}{a^2}=38$, find $a-\dfrac{1}{a}$.

I was considering to find $a$ by itself, but it doesn't work because of all the powers. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Note that $\left(a-\cfrac 1a\right)^2=a^2-2+\cfrac 1{a^2}$

This kind of thing comes up occasionally with powers of $a+\cfrac 1a$ too.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, could you edit my question so that it has the proper symbols? It would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: @MarkZakhem I addition to this very nice answer, it might be useful for you to note that any bi-quadratic equation such as yours is easy to solve. Indeed, to solve $X^4+aX^2+b$, you first let $Y=X^2$ and solve an ordinary quadratic equation. Then, you take square roots of the solutions in $Y$.